# Having trouble launching server with Java. Display error [Cent OS 6]

Tags: linux

[root@null folder]# java -classpath bin:deps/poi.jar:deps/mysql.jar:deps/mina.jar:deps/slf4j.jar:deps/slf4j-nop.jar:deps/jython.jar:log4j-1.2.15.jar: server.Server

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
        *at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        *at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
        *at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:110)
        *at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:81)
      *  at java.awt.Window.initGC(Window.java:467)
     *   at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:487)
        at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:536)
        at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420)
        at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:385)
       * at javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:180)
        at server.util.ControlPanel.(ControlPanel.java:20)
        at server.Server.(Server.java:83)

I'm using a Terminal for this and not a GUI.

Comment: Can this help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416652/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-lwjgl-in-java-libr

Comment: The error is pretty explicit on what's blowing up:  it can't find `libXext.so.6`.  Make sure you have the dependencies you need on your box.

Comment: Are you running a shell as **root** from X11?  You need to be able to run a display.  Try running `xcalc`, etc from the same shell.

Comment: yes I am running shell on root.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it appears you don't have a valid instance of X server running. Some libraries for Java require that one be running.  From my research installing `Xvfb` (`X Virtual Frame Buffer`) is the solution to your problem.  Once it is installed you will need to go to `etc/profile`

Then add, inside profile, these lines.

```
if [ -f /usr/X11R6/bin/Xvfb ]; then
/usr/X11R6/bin/Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x16
fi

export DISPLAY=localhost:1.0
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to install Xext devel: http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libXext.so.6 I can't remember exactly what is the library name for centos ... but it is something like:

yum install libXext-dev

or a variation of it (devel, xext-dev, xext-devel, libxext ... or something similar). I don't have CentOS here :(

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I installed it, and now i get
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/lib/amd64/xawt/libmawt.so: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file:

Comment: do the same with Xrender :)

Comment: All was fixed, now i get
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable. I believe it is something to do with setting a display. I'm using terminal and not a GUI to launch a server made in Java.

Comment: Yes, if you connect via a terminal, without allowing X forwarding to your host you will not have graphics. What OS are you on?

Comment: Cent OS 6 is the distribution

Comment: try this: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/java-lang-internalerror-can%27t-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-%270-0%27-as-the-value-917776/

Comment: xhost isn't a valid command on Cent OS 6 :/. someone was mentioning to me "screen".

Comment: maybe this? http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/installing-xhost-on-rh-879680/

Comment: still cannot open display :/ i'll figure it out, thanks so much for your help!