# Automatically move libraryDependencies (natives) to Java's Library Path or set Library Path to the location of the dependencies

Tags: java, scala, sbt, java.library.path, library-path

I'm here to ask for help to **automate** a process I saw no other solution than doing it manually.

In one of my projects, I have the following dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.lwjgl" % "lwjgl" % "3.0.0a",
    "org.lwjgl" % "lwjgl-platform" % "3.0.0a" classifier "natives-windows" classifier "natives-linux" classifier "natives-osx"
)
```

This downloads both, the actual .jar and the natives for each platform. Developing this way is no problem. All the dependencies are there and all classes are found.

But *compiling* and running the application turns out to be a *major* problem, as you'd get:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path

Now what I do is more than suboptimal, it actually defeats the whole purpose of using managed-libraries: I manually copy the jar and natives to a `lib`-directory which is (by default) the sbt default location for unmanaged libraries.

But if I manually have to move it, I can download it manually as well and leave it completely out of the `sbt`-file. Not really what I want to do.

How can I automate this process? Generally I thought about two ideas, but have no idea how to properly translate them to `sbt`:

1. Automatically set the `-Djava.library.path` to the path where the
   dependencies are located. This path differs from OS to OS and of
   course I'd like to be able to actually export the project as a
   **runnable** `jar` some day ;) without major drawbacks or copying around again.
2. Do what I do now, but automatically: So, move the dependencies to the `lib`-folder.

I can't be the only one struggling with this (or well, maybe I am) but all I found was two "solutions":

1. "Do it manually": [Can't get LWJGL to run using IDEA and SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222360/cant-get-lwjgl-to-run-using-idea-and-sbt) which I - as pointed out in length - find really (less than) **suboptimal**
2. Use https://github.com/philcali/sbt-lwjgl-plugin, but:

> Currently SBT version 0.13 is not supported.

is far less than suboptimal (again) :(

Any more ideas? I can't imagine nobody having to deal with natives at all!

Comment: I've hit exactly the same problem and have also solved it by handling natives outside of SBT. I'd really like to see an answer to this.